# Setting up RDP into VirtualBox over the internet

Tags: networking, virtualbox, remote-desktop

I am new to VirtualBox and networking in general. I am trying to setup an RDP connection into VM via VirtualBox (7.0.12). I want people over the internet to be able to remote into the VM.

Here is what I have done so far. VirtualBox extensions have been installed. The VM is currently up and running Windows 11 Home and is connected to the internet. I have enabled remote display (auth: Guest) on port 3392 and have a bridged adapter connection running. Running `ipconfig` in the VM returns the following:

```
auditer@Audit-VirtualBo MINGW64 ~
$ ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Unknown adapter Tailscale:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : taila6c11.ts.net
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fd7a:115c:a1e0:ab12:4843:cd96:6258:af02
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d8ff:5060:f230:9168%5
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 100.88.175.2
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fdd5:ed40:1d7c:c961:46c4:cc1b:f08f:1cd0
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fdd5:ed40:1d7c:c961:54ea:493a:4d2c:9bc7
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e164:3152:178d:6ef3%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.39.114
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.39.1
```

Now I believe the next move is to add a port forwarding rule in the router. However, when I attempt to assign the "Internal IP address" 192.168.39.114, it states "Invalid Data. Internal IP Address is not in LAN!". Any help is much appreciated!

Details:

- Host OS: Windows 11 Home
- VM OS: Windows 11 Home
- VirtualBox Ver: 7.0.12
- Router: Netgear

Comment: Hi @u1686_grawity, It is set to bridged adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have enabled remote display (auth: Guest) on port 3392 and have a bridged adapter connection running

With the VirtualBox "Remote display" feature, you are not supposed to be connecting to the guest IP address – you're supposed to be connecting to the *host* address, i.e. to VirtualBox itself (which gives you a console view) rather than anything inside the VM.

(That is, it's a completely different thing from the "Remote desktop" feature part of Windows, it just happens to be using the same protocol and client app.)

This does not explain the "not in LAN" error you get from your router, but either way the VM's IP address is not the right address to use.

Comment: I see, so for my use case, the VirtualBox's Remote Display is not what I am looking for? It also seems that perhaps the IP address that should've been used is the Host OS. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Well, I'm not sure – usually you'd rather set up Remote Desktop on the guest system instead (and indeed set up the port-forward to the guest IP), but it depends on your needs. Direct RDP to the guest OS will have individual user accounts and individual logon sessions, while VBox "Remote display" will always attach to the same 'console' session like VNC, which can be either useful or not.